# Integral with a dependent range

Tags: real-analysis, integration

For some constant $a \in (0,1)$, [Wolfram-Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Ba/x,%20%7Bx,%20a%5E2,%20Sqrt%5Ba%5D%7D,%20%20%20Assumptions%20-%3E%20%7B0%20%3C%20a%20%3C%201%7D%5D) yields

$$\int_{a^2} ^\sqrt a\frac{a}{x} \text{dx} =-\frac{3}{2} a \log(a)$$

How does one approach such an integral?
I feel like the solution is probably very elementary, but I don't see it.

Comment: Why didn't you bother asking yourself the question? Or go to sleep before posting on MSE? I feel like looking at myself when I am damn tired past 2a.m. and trying to say something intelligent while it just won't come out.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: See the edit, i did a simple mistake I did not find so I was confused. And yeah it was indeed a stupid question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $a \log(x)$ is an antiderivative.  Now evaluate it at $x=\sqrt{a}$ and at $x = a^2$, and subtract.  $\frac{a \log(a)}{2} - 2 a \log(a) = -\frac{3}{2} a \log(a)$.

Comment: Thank you, I will accept your answer in a few minutes :), seems like my intuition was right on this one..

Answer (score 1):

$a\log (x)|^{\sqrt a}_{a^2}=  a\log a^{1/2}-a\log a^2={1\over 2}a\log a -2a\log a=-{3\over2}a\log a$.

Where did you get $-{1\over2}$?

Comment: *facepalm* I did a mistake when simplifying the expression. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

$\int \mathrm1/x {d}x$ =log x
now put in the values 
=>1/2log a -2log a =-3/2 log a